# Facebook PHP-SDK + jQuery AJAX

Tags: facebook, security, jquery, facebook-php-sdk

Im creating a Facebook app using PHP-SDK.

In order to find a user's uid I do:

`index.php` file

```
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
if($user_id == 0) // not logged in user
  {
    // do stuff to log in user and get the current user id
  }
```

Inside `index.php` file I have the following jQuery code:

```
   var get_url =
      'do_stuff.php?id=' + <?php echo $user_id; ?> + '&field1=' + field1 + '&field2='+ field2;

       $.get(get_url, function(data) {
          alert("data: " + data);
       });
```

`do_stuff.php` inserts data on my MySQL database based on `field1` and `field2`. I want to be sure that the data inserted are really from user with `$user_id`. And not just somebody who did a fake request like:

```
http://myapp.com/do_stuff.php?id=fake_user_id&field1=...&field2=...
```

So, I added the `$user_id = $facebook->getUser();` at `do_stuff.php` but instead of returning the current user id (which is visible at `index.php`), it returns `0` which means no user is logged in. Why is this?

How I can fix it? So I will be sure that the data inserted on my MySQL database are from a real user and not a fake one?

Answer (score 0):

This is because as far as do_stuff.php is concerned, no one is logged in. You probably need to look at capturing the access token and using that in do_stuff.php.